# MVC4: Move SQLServer session into external hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I want to move my session database from my local machine into external hosting. Why? Because I do not have access to use

```
aspnet_regsql.ext -d DBName -S ServerName -U User -P Password -ssadd -sstype c
```

on the external hosting.

I tried to backup and restore. The problem is that the name of the database on the external hosting server starts with prefix, which will make the name to be different from my local machine DBName.

I want to just have 1 file that I can move to any external hosting server and the name is dynamic (means the name of the DB will be different each time I install my website).

I am considering of using `custom SQL session state`, but I have no knowledge of making one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use config file and config file transformations for each deployment? So that database connection string will be substituted with the right one during the process of deployment.
https://forums.asp.net/t/1993077.aspx?How+to+Change+The+Default+Database+name+In+MVC+4

Comment: Well... what im trying to achieve here, I am making a CMS. So I need to bundle everything into 1 installation package which include databases and the application itself. The problem with ur suggestion is that I need to re-bundle and recreate the state database everytime I install to the new client.